# jQuery: How to validate if 6 out of 56 checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have found quite a bit on how to validate using jQuery whether one of the checkboxes in form is checked but my issue goes beyond that:
Currently I am working on a form (Johari window) that requires the user to check 6 out of 56 items using a simple form with 56 checkboxes.

Could you point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**
This did the trick, thanks again for your help!

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 6 ){
        e.preventDefault();     alert("Please select 6 items!");
    } });
```

Comment: Wow, 7 answers in literally seconds... I am amazed! Thank you guys!

Comment: This did the trick in the end btw:               $('form').submit(function(e){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length < 6 ){
        e.preventDefault();
 alert("Please select 6 items!");
    }
});

Answer (score 1):

check length of checked check-boxes

```
$('input[type="checkobox"]:checked').length;
```

You can do like this

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if($('input[type="checkobox"]:checked').length < 6 ){
        e.preventDefault(); //to stop form submission 
    }
});
```

References

[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)

[.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the number of checked checkboxes:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked").length;
```

Then only submit your form if more than 6 have been checked:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if($('input[type="checkbox"').is(":checked").length < 6 ){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

uses [.is(selector)](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a js function using jQuery :

```
function isValid(){
    return $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length == 6;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state how you are doing your validation, but something like:

```
if ($(":checked" ).length < 6)
{
      //Not valid
}
```

Assumes that the checkboxes are the only 'selectable' inputs on the page.

Note - also assumes that more than 6 checked is also ok?

Answer (score 0):

Easy:

```
if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 6) {
   // Do whatever you need to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
if ($('input:checkbox:checked').length == 6) {
    // validation successful
} else {
    // return an error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very different approach just for fyi:

```
var checkBox = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
var num = 0;
$.each(checkBox, function(){
    var checked = $(this).is(":checked");
    if(checked){
        if(num < 6){
            num++;
        } else {
            //Do something
        }
    }
});
```